# How to show the first three items of array and hide other?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am quite new in react. I have an array of comments.
How can i show just the first three items in this array, not all?

```js
{item.Comments.map((item, key) => (
  <View key={key} style={{marginVertical:10,marginLeft:12}}>
    <View style={{flexDirection:"row"}}>
      <Text style={{color:"rgba(0,0,0,0.7)"}}> {item.username}</Text>
    </View>
    <Text style={{padding:5}}> {item.comment}</Text>
  </View>
))}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
{item.Comments.slice(0,3).map((item, key) => (
  <View key={key} style={{marginVertical:10,marginLeft:12}}>
    <View style={{flexDirection:"row"}}>
      <Text style={{color:"rgba(0,0,0,0.7)"}}> {item.username}</Text>
    </View>
    <Text style={{padding:5}}> {item.comment}</Text>
  </View>
))}
```

Notice the only change I made was adding `.slice(0,3)` before using `.map` - this will grab the first 3 elements of your `item.Comments` array (see documentation on [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)), then you can immediately call `.map` on that array of 3 items. It even works if somehow your `item.Comments` array has less than 3 items :D

**Note**: The second parameter in the `.map` function is the current index in the array you're mapping over, so where you have called the parameter `key`, normally people call that `index`, and still assign that to the `key` property in the `View` component.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I have another question could you please help me!? how can add a date that passed from posting the comment?

Comment: Hmm since your `Comments` array is an array of objects, and it looks like each object has properties `username` and `comment`, is there also a property called `date` on each object?

Comment: No i did't add. I am thinking that i store the date of  posting in database then comparing that date with the current date.Is that correct ?

Comment: Yeah that should work :D You might get some use out of [this library](https://github.com/Ihapmustapha/since-time-ago) or [this one](https://momentjs.com/)